# Increasing size of Win8 hot corners?

Tags: windows-8

Does anyone know if there is a way to increase the size of the hot corners in windows 8?

Struggling to find any information regarding settings for the tiny corner hotspots.

Comment: Having trouble finding the hot spot?

Comment: i can find it. my trouble is a client of mine is rolling out some touchscreens and they have a large bezel, making it difficult to select the corner hotspots.

Comment: Cant believe i'm having this much trouble increasing the sixe of the corners. surely there is an easy way

Comment: This question is not on topic here, it is not a programming question.  Use google, query for "increase windows 8 corners" and take the first hit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the registry key

```
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop
```

with the value

```
MouseCornerClipLength
```

Valid values are 0-20.

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0bbb0fc2-61e7-46ea-850b-fcb4e021335e/tweak-windows-8-hot-corners)

Comment: Just in case someone doesn't know what HKCU means...  HKey_Current_User.  
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976337.aspx